How to ignore warnings when using tryCatch
I'm running iterations of a script that uses the neuralnet() function to fit predictor variables to an outcome variable. This is done in a for loop to generate 100 replicates. Most iterations throw (harmless) warnings that can be ignored, but in about 1 in 10 instances the model fails to converge and throws an error. I would like to skip the cases that give an error (writing a placeholder into an output array to track these cases) while ignoring warnings, using the following (as the relevant part of the code inside of the for loop), based on the suggestions in:
Suppress warnings using tryCatch in R
skip_to_next = FALSE
tryCatch(nn_predicted = predict(nn_model_training, data.frame(x)), warning = function(w){},error = function(e){skip_to_next = TRUE})

if(skip_to_next){
    aucs = c(-1)
    AUC_Mat = rbind(AUC_Mat, aucs)
    next
}

nn_my_auc = auc(y_test, nn_predicted)
aucs = c(nn_my_auc)
AUC_Mat = rbind(aucs)

Every iteration results in a skip and returns the -1 placeholder. Because only a small fraction of the 100 iterations are giving errors, the only explanation I can think of is that the warnings are not being ignored and skip_to_next is being set to true. Is this the case, or is something else potentially causing this problem?

The way you are using tryCatch is misguided, e.g. try tryCatch(stop(), error = function(e) test <- 1); test: the test variable is not created. Try instead e.g. test <- tryCatch(stop('a'), error = function(e) e); if (inherits(test, 'error')) do_something(). Alternatively, you might try using purrr::safely().

it should be warning = ... not warnings = ... and if all you want to do is ignore the message and continue, wrap predict in suppressWarnings otherwise you will lose the models with any warning

@Axeman - what in my use of tryCatch is incorrect (apart from warnings rather than warning, as rawr pointed out)? In your suggested alternative of tryCatch(stop()..., where would my function be passed?

I'd strongly second the recommendation to use purrr::safely. It works the way a lot of new users want tryCatch to work.

@Max as Axeman's comment's illustrate, doing assignment inside the tryCatch() functions isn't a good way to do things (generally with R, assignments done inside functions have no effect outside the function). Their example shows that you can assign the tryCatch result, test <- tryCatch(...). But that doesn't mesh very well with the way your code is written, hence the excellent recommendation to try purrr::safely() instead.

@Gregor Thomas - I'm looking at the documentation for purrr:::safely() and it isn't clear to me if the otherwise applies only to errors or to warnings as well as errors. If it's the latter, is there a straightforward way to ignore warnings with safely() while processing errors "otherwise"? Should I just wrap my function in suppressWarnings inside of safely()?

safely() doesn't do anything to warnings. If you want to suppress warnings, wrapping in suppressWarnings() would certainly do the trick. (There's also purrr::quietly() which would work similarly to suppressWarnings(), and you can read this discussion of a feature request to combine the two which was deemed as getting too complicated for purrr.)

@Max, you'd want something along the lines of nn_predicted <- tryCatch(predict(nn_model_training, data.frame(x)), warning = function(w) { }, error = function(e) e). Then instead of if (skip_to_next) have if (inherits(nn_predicted, "error")). It's a bit hard to specific and correct without a reproducible example, as always.
